# Gulpfile that includes other gulp files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I wrote some wrapper functions for using gulp, such as `buildJs`, `buildCss`, etc, that simply wrap some things like concatenation, minification, transpiling, etc.

I have these functions and all the required node modules in the main file, `gulpfile.js`

Then I wrote all my build tasks (eg `gulp.task('dostuff, function(){});`) in two other files, `buildA.js` and `buildB.js`.

In my main `gulpfile.js` after I `require` the necessary node modules like `gulp`, I then thought I could `require` `buildA.js` and `buildB.js` and it would be as if they were just copy-pasted into the file. Obviously this doesn't work, because when I try to run a `gulp` task from file `buildA.js`, it tells me that `gulp` is not defined when it hits `gulp.task....`

I also did not `import` or `export` anything in any file.

What can I do to include my product specific gulp files in one master gulp file, and be able to call `gulp.task` specific to each build file, from the main gulp file, as if they were actually in the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using the require-dir, https://www.npmjs.com/package/require-dir
Assume your buildA.js and buildB.js are located in ./gulp directory, you can use this line to include them in your gulpfile:
    require('require-dir')('./gulp');

Comment: What does this accomplish as oppose to using regular `require` ?

Comment: My understanding is when you use regular require, you will get the module which defined in that file, since gulp task are not defined as a module use module.export, require not work for it.